# Using JSON returned object in GetDynamicValueProperties

Tags: json, wcf, rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have a REST Wcf method call that returns the following for me..

```
{"GetDTOTestResult":{"DateTimeNow":"The DTOTest was returned at Sunday, September 14, 2014","Message":null}}
```

How can I load this in a Workflow's GetDynamicValueProperties activity? How should I setup the Properties of the activity??.. I tried using "DateTimeNow" and AssignTo a local string variable. But I cant see the result.

What am I missing her??

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution... I had to mention

```
GetDTOTestResult/DateTimeNow
```

as the path for the property in the GetDynamicValueProperties activity.